# Can I use Redis instead of Mysql in Magento? How?

Tags: mysql, redis

I want to use Redis in Magento instead of mysql? I do like how to done it?

Answer (score 1):

Good day.
Redis is not a replacement MySQL.
If you you want to use NoSQL with Magento, you must choose DB with guarantee the preservation to Storage 
For Example - MongoDB